# req.body is undefined - only default mongodb id is getting pushed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

I have been trying to use post request to insert data to the mongodb using mongoose, however I see that req.body is being shown as undefined. document is getting inserted in database, however only default object id is getting inserted.

This is how I send request to Postman

{
name:"wewe",
price:43}

```js
//Post.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/tutorialkart");

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    price: Number
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Groduct', productSchema);

//app.js

var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var Post = require('./Post')

var app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())



app.post('/api/posts', function (req, res, next) {
    var post = new Post({
        name: req.body.name,
        price: req.body.price
    })
    console.log("Log "+post.name );
    post.save(function (err, post) {
        if (err) { return next(err) }
        res.json(201, post)
    })
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server listening on', 3000)
})
```

[image: MongoDB]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your request in Postman (you removed the screenshot which showed these issues):

- it's not formatted as proper JSON, but as a Javascript object
- you're sending it as `text/plain`, not `application/json`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked, you were right about both points :) Its solved!

Answer (score 1):

> This is how I send request to Postman
>
> { name:"wewe", price:43}

One of two things is happening:

- Either you aren't setting a `Content-Type` header in the request so the JSON parsing middleware you set up isn't being triggered **or**
- You have, but since your JSON is invalid, it is failing to parse it.

You have to write valid JSON!

You can test your JSON with [JSON Lint](https://jsonlint.com/).

In particular, property names in JSON must be **strings** and cannot be identifiers. Strings in JSON must be delimited with `"` characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot is not visible/trouble opening the screenshot. You need to be more specific with your question.

1. I think mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/tutorialkart"); here you need to specify the PORT localhost:27017
2. <strike>Make sure you defined the names "name" and "price" in your HTML/EJS and setting their value as the data you are trying to insert into database.</strike>
3. Use **new** before mongoose.model, mongoose.Schema
4. `app.use(bodyParser.json())` should be `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`

Comment: Could you please check the attached screenshot again? Yous see that default ID is only getting pushed. Also I have not developed a HTML page yet, I am just using POSTMAN and this is my request body: {
    name:"wewe",
   price:43}

Comment: Check the fixes now and let me know.